# Как с помощью JavaScript при нажатии кнопки(Выбрать файл) прописать путь к файлу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как с помощью JavaScript при нажатии кнопки(Выбрать файл) прописать путь к файлу? Т.е. при нажатии кнопки, чтобы уже был выбран прописанный файл автоматически

Comment: Вроде как по правилам безопасности жска не имеет доступ к этому... Можно посмотреть последнее изменение, тип и размер файла, но путь - я не слышал...

Answer (score 1):

Сделать так в современных браузерах нельзя из соображений безопасности.
Ни файл выбрать автоматом, ни адрес файла узнать, ни директорию дефолтную задать.

Потому что проблем с безопасностью и совместимостью было бы реально очень много, а удобства очень мало.

Например если просто взять и дать возможность предустанавливать выбранный файл, то это дало бы возможность злоумышленнику незаметно для юзера грузить какой-нибудь файл с конфигами по дефолтному пути.

Если дать предустанаваливать часть пути, то это дало бы злоумышленнику узнать, как у вас файловая система устроена. Например есть ли у вас на компьютере скажем папочка D:/PornWithPonies.

Поэтому нельзя и все тут.